# Consumir Webservices com Android - Retrofit ou Volley?

Tags: android, retrofit, volley

A pergunta é justamente esta: para consumir Webservices com Android - Retrofit ou Volley? Achei os dois complicados à principio, mas lendo a documentação me pareceu que retrofit pode ser algo menos complicado. O que sugerem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrofit é uma das mais poderosas e populares bibliotecas de `HTTP Client` para `Android` e `Java`. Eu recomendaria a utilização do `Retrofit2`. Sem dúvidas alguma ela irá facilitar a sua vida quando você der uma estuda na mesma, pois um dos grandes diferenciais da Retrofit2 é a sua 'Simplicidade'.  Mas caso você seja iniciante, eu recomendaria você fazer tudo na 'UNHA', desde criar a conexão para o `Webservice` até a desserialização do seu objeto consumido, pois assim você iria ver como funciona o fluxo de consumo.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sugestão @Matheus

Answer (score 0):

Eu "*tenho*" (a empresa que eu trabalho tem hahaha) uma aplicação em **Android Nativo** e eu consumo WS mas não uso nenhuma dessas duas ferramentas por um motivo bem importante no meu ponto de vista, **manutenção**. E sinceramente sugiro ***fazer o que você precisa*** para consumir o WS dessa forma não terá nada "*sobrando*" na sua aplicação (você faz **só** o que precisa e **nada mais**), para desenvolvimento mobile você precisa levar em conta os "*trechos sem uso*" do seu código.
Não é demorado ***nem difícil*** consumir um WS (a realidade é que mistificamos muito isso), e se você precisar ***mudar qualquer coisa*** você tem a oportunidade e nada te impede.

Ps. Como disse é minha **recomendação**, se as opiniões forem diferentes ok (acontece).

Comment: Obrigado @WebFerreira . Sou estudante e preciso criar uma aplicacao que consome uma API desenvolvida pelo professor. Ele deixou livre por isso estou à procura de solucoes para este trabalho.